# No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'string' in EF Core Cosmos Db based .NET 5.0 app

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

I want to remodel the ASP.NET Identity tables to use in Cosmos Db based .NET 5.0 Identity Server app. The idea is to embed the role names of a user in a string array inside the user document.

Hence I have extended `IdentityUser` to become:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [JsonProperty("uRoles")]
    public List<string> uRoles { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
    public string Type => "ApplicationUser";
}
```

**Entity Configuration**

```
builder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
builder.HasPartitionKey(_ => _.Id);
builder.Property(_ => _.ConcurrencyStamp).IsETagConcurrency();

builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Profile);
builder.OwnsMany(p => p.uRoles);
```

I am seeding roles in `Startup.cs` and as soon as the dbContext queries db for roles, I get the following exception:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'string'. The
> following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to
> properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'string(char[]
> value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length' in 'string(char[]
> value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind 'value' in
> 'string(Char* value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length' in
> 'string(Char* value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind 'value'
> in 'string(SByte* value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length'
> in 'string(SByte* value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind
> 'value', 'startIndex', 'length', 'enc' in 'string(SByte* value, int
> startIndex, int length, Encoding enc)'; cannot bind 'c', 'count' in
> 'string(char c, int count)'; cannot bind 'value' in
> 'string(ReadOnlySpan value)'.

Interestingly, it is because of `List<string> uRoles` property inside `ApplicationUser`. As soon as I remove the `uRoles` from the `ApplicationUser` class, the error goes away.

I have written a custom user and roles store, configured the DbContext and all using EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider. The issue is not caused because of those things. It's the `uRoles` property.

Comment: No db provider (except Npgsql) supports list of primitive values (strings, numbers etc.). Cosmos is not an exception.

Comment: @IvanStoev any workarounds for my situation then?

Comment: Using standard list of entities? e.g. `List<UserRole>` where `UserRole` is `[Owned]public class UserRole { public string Name { get; set; } }`